# xCode 8 - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, xcode

I have taught myself VBA and have been using it extensively for the past 4 years (factory, multi-inhertiance, polymorphic design), so I have some understanding of advanced programming techniques.  I am teaching myself C++ as a way of expanding my skill set, but the error messages received from the compiler can leave one scratching their heads for quite some time.  The error message I receive "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" is a common topic and one [usually] caused by something very simple.  I have reviewed many of them to no avail.  I am at a complete loss.

The line in the error message is as follows:

```
"operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>  >&, Point<double> const&)", referenced from:

  TestPoint() in TestPoint.o
```

TestPoint.cpp contains the following line:

```
cout << "p1: " << p1 << endl;
```

which is the proximate cause of the error, but I understand that the source of the error stems from the "p1" object referenced above.

The header file for the "p1" object contains the following definition:

```
//template <class T>
friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Point<T>& p);
```

along with the following include statements:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
```

While the source file contains:

```
template <class G>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Point<G>& p)
{//Print
    os << "(" << p.m_first << "," << p.m_second << ")\n";
    return os;
}
```

With these include statements:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Point.hpp"
```

I am also attempting to learn about templates, which some of my programming buddies have told me is a difficult topic on its own.

The definition and the implementation appear to match, but I have no idea why the compiler is complaining.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I am working with Xcode 8.1

Answer (score 0):

My issue has to do with templates and the interaction of "friend" operators.. a friend of mine found this which appears to address my issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476535/c-overloading-operators-on-template-class-throws-linker-errors